# iOS) How to add default separator of uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

Defaultly, it provides default separator between cells not for the first and last cell.

So first cell has no upper separator and last cell has no footer separator.

I need default one, not to make as UIView...

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom border you can add a 'Dummy' cell of height 1. That will get you the default border.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this putting small header and footer on your tableview.
You can create those with custom cells in your storyboard.